# How to benchmark server performance?

Tags: apache, benchmarking

I'm trying to setup a web server that will run apache or something similar. I also want to try out nginx, and some caching.

How do I conduct a test to see if my server performance like req/sec. changes everytime I'm tuning a configuration?

Comment: post your question on http://serverfault.com/

Answer (score 1):

[ab - Apache HTTP server benchmarking tool](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/programs/ab.html) should help you a lot.

Comment: Thanks for the link. But what if I were to take out apache and use something like nginx + fastcgi. Can I still use ab or is there a more generic http benchmarking tool?

Comment: I'm sure you can use this tool with any web server.

Comment: I keep getting: "Send request failed!
apr_socket_recv: Connection reset by peer (54)
Total of 3 requests completed". How do/can I get around this? Thanks?